Confusion About .NET to JavaScript Interoperability in Blazor - Method Call Sequence
I'm working on a Blazor project where I need to call a .NET method from JavaScript, but I'm encountering some confusion with the sequence of method calls. Here’s a simplified version of my code:
@page "/call-dotnet-2"
@implements IDisposable
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<PageTitle>Call .NET 2</PageTitle>

<h1>Call .NET Example 2</h1>

<p>
    <label>
        Name: <input @bind="name" />
    </label>
</p>

<p>
    <button @onclick="TriggerDotNetInstanceMethod">
        Trigger .NET instance method
    </button>
</p>

<p>
    @result
</p>

@code {
    private string? name;
    private string? result;
    private DotNetObjectReference<CallDotnet2>? objRef;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        objRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
    }

    public async Task TriggerDotNetInstanceMethod()
    {
        result = await JS.InvokeAsync<string>("sayHello1", objRef);
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public string GetHelloMessage() => $"Hello, {name}!";

    public void Dispose() => objRef?.Dispose();
}

Javascript code:
<script>
  window.sayHello1 = (dotNetHelper) => {
    return dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('GetHelloMessage');
  };
</script>

I need to call a .NET method from the browser using JavaScript (for example, via the browser console or an event handler of a JavaScript slider library). However, my current implementation shows that the call is being made from .NET to JavaScript and then back to .NET (.NET -> JavaScript -> .NET), which isn't what I intend.

Have you read and tested - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-8.0?

The codes is from your link.
